# How to import android.device

Tags: java, android, device

I'd like to use ScanManager from `android.device.ScanManager`. But I get the `error "cannot resolve symbol 'device'"` on the import line.

Can somebody tell me what I am missing ?

Answer (score -1):

Use this library in your `gradle` file at app level it works out great

If Android Studio >= 3.0

`implementation 'com.github.DeveloperPaul123:SimpleBluetoothLibrary:1.5.1'`

**Else use**

`compile 'com.github.DeveloperPaul123:SimpleBluetoothLibrary:1.5.1'`

I have used it to detect Bluetooth Hardware devices and interface Android devices with them

The GATT Profile in Bluetooth for Android has a different class named `BluetoothGatt` and `BluetoothDevice` to access the bluetooth devices.

You can import this class as well if you want this ScanManager classes set from [here]
(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/master/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/ScanManager.java)