# How to use android.device

Tags: android

I'm trying to user android.device but the Android Studio can't see the library, Do you know what implantation I need to add to gradle or what I need to do for using it? or if I need to use AndroidX

I'll need to use those libraries:

```
import android.device.ScanManager;
import android.device.scanner.configuration.PropertyID;
import android.device.scanner.configuration.Symbology;
import android.device.scanner.configuration.Triggering;
```

[image: android.device]

Comment: Can you share a source to Next Library ? 
android.device.ScanManager this packages not in android documentation .(https://developer.android.com/reference)

Comment: Next isn't a library I edited the post

Comment: ok. can you please explain why do you want to use those packages ?
Also where do you find those packages ?

Comment: Seems like the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809843/how-to-import-android-device